# Homebrew - What's the difference between `python@3` and `python3`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I have python 2.7.14 installed via homebrew, and I'd like to install the latest version of python 3 via homebrew as well. When I search for "python3" I see the following results.

```
$ brew search python3
==> Formulae
boost-python3                      python3                            python@3

If you meant "python3" specifically:
It was migrated from homebrew/cask to homebrew/core.
```

Why is there both `python@3` and `python3`? What's the difference?

Comment: Should it be migrated, or do I need to move it?

Comment: Uh, that's weird. How did I bork this up and get those unsupported modules?

Comment: (Happy to move this to chat)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178555/discussion-between-user3-1415927-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 1):

Right now, there are only two distinct Formula for Python in homebrew-core: [`python`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb), and [`python@2`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python@2.rb).

`python@3` and `python3` are both aliases to `Formula/python.rb`. Thus, they're just different names that install the same package.

See the two aliases:

- [`Aliases/python@3`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/e6662554d2a3fa0074fcaa18e0d591ff5ab862cb/Aliases/python%403)
- [`Aliases/python3`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/e6662554d2a3fa0074fcaa18e0d591ff5ab862cb/Aliases/python3)

...both pointing to:

- [`Formula/python.rb`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/e6662554d2a3fa0074fcaa18e0d591ff5ab862cb/Formula/python.rb)

---

To find this yourself, use `brew info` -- for example, `brew info python@3` -- and look for the `From:` line with a URL to the formula which was used. For example, this line might look like:

```
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python.rb
```