# a couple Python versioning questions (touching Homebrew and venv)

Tags: python, homebrew, python-venv

I read the Homebrew [notes on Python](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python.html) but I'm still a bit confused based on a couple specific situations described below. I'm also starting to use venv and a bit confused how that works. So here are a couple questions regarding how both of those handle Python versioning. Thanks in advance.

1. `brew list` shows both `python3` and `python`. This is a bit confusing to me because I have also read that Python 2 is referred to as `python@2`, and I don't think I have Python 2 installed. So I'm wondering why there are 2 different formulae which both seem to mean "Python 3". (EDIT: I might be able to answer this question myself, I just found another mention that python3 is simply an alias to python: [Homebrew - What's the difference between `python@3` and `python3`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971477/homebrew-whats-the-difference-between-python3-and-python3))
2. I used the following command to create a virtual environment in a folder: `python3 -m venv venv`. Now within `./venv/bin` I have the files in the below screenshot.

I am basically wondering why I have 2 files for Python and 3 files for pip in this virtual environment (the Python files are just aliases,  but the pip files are actual executables from what I can tell). From running the version commands (`python --version`, `python3 --version`, `pip -V`, `pip3 -V`) I can see they are the same version, so I am wondering why I got multiple files.

Is this just for convenience? Does it matter which one I use? And why specifically include a file `pip3.7` but not do the same thing for Python? Does this have anything to do with how I'm using Homebrew or is this just a venv thing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just for convenience. On some OSes, like MacOS, where you have both `python` ( Python 2 ) and `python3` ( Python 3 ) having both `python` and `python3` in a `venv` is nice if you've already written scripts that do something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as they'll "just work" with the new `venv` environment. The same holds true for the different `pip` too.